# Upload media gallery from front-end side on WordPress related to user

Tags: php, wordpress

I stack on this function `media_handle_upload( $file_id, $post_id, $post_data, $overrides );`

Is there a way to upload media (image, video, etc.) relatated to user ID?

I need to create custom page where registered user upload media and they only need to see own media realated to ther user profile ID.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I would add meta relating to the media post ID using the add post meta function. In this post meta I would store the user ID of the uploading user or any user which I want to be able to view the image.

```
add_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique);
```

In the above the post ID would be the media item post ID, the meta key would be 'user_id' or something similar, and the value would be the user ID. Then when searching for images for that user you can just do a  search on the post meta table for the meta value matching the users ID.

You can read up on the add_post_meta function here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta

Answer (score 1):

I used this code in video and audio upload for frontend.

```
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $videos, $post_id );

add_post_meta($post_id, '$meta_key', $attach_id);
```

Comment: This can be workable. Generaly, I need one page to create like user gallery and all attachments to assign to that page. Only I listing media by post_meta per user. Right? This will not ovewrkill WordPress?

Comment: I used this type of code,

    $my_post = array(
        'post_title'    => "title",
                'post_content'  => "desc",
                'post_status'   => 'publish',
                'post_type'     => 'page' OR 'post',
                'post_author'   => 8
            );
$post_id = wp_insert_post($my_post,$wp_error );
$video_str = 1.mp4;
$videos = SERVER_NAME.$video_str;
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $videos, $post_id );
add_post_meta($post_id, '$meta_key', $attach_id);
add_post_meta($post_id, '$meta_value', '$meta_value_id');

Answer (score 1):

```
 I used this type of code,

    $my_post = array(
        'post_title'    => "title",
                'post_content'  => "desc",
                'post_status'   => 'publish',
                'post_type'     => 'page' OR 'post',
                'post_author'   => 8
            );
$post_id = wp_insert_post($my_post,$wp_error );
$video_str = 1.mp4;
$videos = SERVER_NAME.$video_str;
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $videos, $post_id );
add_post_meta($post_id, '$meta_key', $attach_id);
add_post_meta($post_id, '$meta_value', '$meta_value_id');
```

Comment: Realy?'$meta_key' variable inside single quotes? Does it work?